# Relacionamento de classes por coleções em JPA2

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa-2.0

Em uma bean que possui uma ligação OneToMany, com outras, por meio de uma HashMap  que anotações devem ser utilizadas?.

```
  @Entity
  class Rodada{
      public HashMap<Pergunta,Resposta> perguntas;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essa relação ficaria melhor estruturada dentro de uma classe wrapper para essas duas entidades:

```
@Entity
public class Questao {

   @Id
   private int id;
   @OneToOne
   private Pergunta pergunta;
   @OneToOne
   private Resposta resposta;

   // getter, setter, hashCode, equals

}
```

Então em sua classe de rodadas:

```
@Entity
public class Rodada {
  //Id omitido
  @OneToMany
  @JoinColumn(name = "rodada_id")
  private Set<Questao> questoes;

  // getter, setter, hashCode, equals  

}
```

Caso ainda assim queira manter da forma que está, segue um exemplo retirado do [SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7525320/how-to-add-a-hashmapstring-object-in-an-entity-class) que pode te ajudar:

```
@ElementCollection
@CollectionTable(name="<name_of_join_table>")
@MapKeyColumn(name="<name_of_map_key_in_table>")
Map<String, Person> personMap;
```